# How to remove line break after a tag

Tags: django, templates, formatting, pretty-print

I use Django template system to do code generation (not only for HTML). I'm somehow troubled by redundant line breaks in django templates.

Here is an example. The template is as below:

```
// something
    {% for element in elements %}
      Element: {{ element.name }},
    {% endfor %}
// something else
```

The rendered output will be:

```
// something

      Element: foo

      Element: bar

// something else
```

Expected rendered output should be:

```
// something
      Element: foo
      Element: bar
// something else
```

After googled a bit, I know I can use `{% spaceless %}` to remove any white spaces in rendered output. It is quite useful for HTML, but will not work for other languages. My current solution is to add a special string after a tag and replace them with empty string in output.

**Is there any better solution to remove line break after a tag?**

Comment: I have same question, I want to create a form builder and generate my model classes dynamically in a python scripts. Too many extra line spaces are killing me. Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your production environment you might consider minifying your html to get that little bit more performance. For example using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-htmlmin.

If you are only interested in the esthetics, then the `.strip` function as noted by e-nouri is probably your best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.strip` on your attributes to strip/trim.

```
// something
    {% for element in elements %}
      Element: {{ element.name.strip }},
    {% endfor %}
// something else
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean to remove line break produced by `{% for %}` and `{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

The line breaks in code shouldn't matter, but you can avoid them when you put everything in one line, which doesn't look that good anymore:

```
{% for element in elements %}Element: {{ element.name.strip }},{% endfor %}
```